# Webpack dev server cannot serving file

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack

Now I'm using Webpack 5 to bundle and serving my html static page. But it not serving my index.html
Here is what I've tried:

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].[fullhash].js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'HMR',
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.html'), // template file
            filename: 'index.html', // output file
        }),
    ],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        hot: true,
        open: true,
    },
    optimization: {
        moduleIds: 'deterministic',
        runtimeChunk: 'single',
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendor: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: 'vendors',
                    chunks: 'all',
                },
            },
        },
    },
};
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>HMR</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Heelo</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open browser I get:
HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found

Need helps

Comment: how does your `index.html` file look like?

Comment: @codemax I edited my question. It's just simple html template with h1 tag

Comment: okay. What's your `webpack-dev-server` version?

Comment: @codemax latest version: ^3.11.2

Comment: cool. what is your start script in `package.json`?

Comment: @codemax I tried: webpack serve

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228300/discussion-between-codemax-and-akashii).

Comment: @codemax I just found that need to upgrade webpack-dev-server to compatibility with webpack@5. thanks for help